# Data migration Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, data-migration

I'm about to migrate data from an old database (Access 2007, with around 30 tables) to a new SQL Server 2008 database structure, with additional information - around 80 tables. I have read a little about it so far, but this is a complete new area for me. Therefore that I ask this question.

---

**A little more detail about what I want to achieve:**

There is an old Access database with Access interface used as a program. The database started small with a few tables around 10 years ago and grew a lot bigger, to around 30 **LARGE** tables at this point of time. The problem facing with this old database is the large data sets (large tables/many columns in 1 table). This not only reduces the query performance, but also limits the data structure and information to be gathered.

As a result, a new database structure had been designed. This is a fully normalized design, with over 80 tables. In fact, the old data is the same, but scattered over many more tables (lets say objects), with few of these table having some extra information about that object, which had not been gathered before. Of course, in future, this data will have to be recorded as well, so a new application (front-end) will be built over this database.

---

Does anybody have any experience or knowledge about literature, good tools or other best practices with which I can transfer my old Access data from the old database into the new, big and normalized design?

I'm digging deeper into SSIS and SSMA at this point, but perhaps someone can point me towards a good direction for my specific needs.

Thank you a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that use of SSIS Package. In the SSIS you can have each source such as Access and each destination such as SQL Server. it use bulk insert and have good performance.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! Following the SSIS Tutorial of Microsoft as we speak

Comment: Accepted your answer. Used SSMA first to convert into MSSQL for ease of use. As I am weeks further working in SSIS, it's a great (and probably the best) tool for these operations - toke me a while to figure that integration services don't come with all version.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you may need to need to address is error 3622, detailed here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190620

Basically you might need to review your code and add the option dbSeeChanges to your OpenRecordset options and Execute statments

```
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
Set oRst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
Set oRst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError)
```

to

```
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges
Set oRst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Set oRst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError + dbSeeChanges)
```